# gpu found. vendor id 10de device if 0x1f07 checking for bad AMD Vulkan driver version

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Emulator closed because of an internal error: gpu found. vendor id 10de device if 0x1f07 checking for bad AMD Vulkan driver version.

How to fixed it?

[image]

Comment: What were you doing when this error occurred and what have you done to try to fix it so far?

Answer (score 4):

First, create a new file named advancedFeatures.ini in `C:\Users\your-log-in-id\.android`. Add the following two lines in it and restart avd.

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMen = on
```

Comment: You may format the code with triple backquotes in order to improve the readability of your message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation, and I was able to work around the problem by reverting to my previous version.  It's very easy to do, you just go to:

Windows Update > View update history > Recovery options > Go Back to the previous version of Windows 10.

AGAIN, NOT A SOLUTION BUT A WORK AROUND MEANWHILE WE FIND THE SOLUTION.

The important thing to note here is that an update is actually important because there are a lot of security patches amongst other improvements in the OS, so it is in our best interest to actually find the solution to this and not leave this problem on the side.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. Just uninstall Android Studio first. Then check whether you have JDK in your machine with the correct Environment path setting, then again install Android Studio. For more detail watch this video and follow the steps

[How to install
JDK & Android studio on windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zx_eFyHRU0)

After that follow [Android Studio environment-setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but this happened to me today!

My problem happened when I add new GPU card and removed the old driver! the card didn't work so I put back my old gpu

WHAT I did is, installing the right Driver!

go to SDK manger remove the Android Emulator and install it again !

Voila !